# Unable to reject edit from question due to focus bug?

Tags: support, status-completed, review, edits, rejected-edits

[image]

When I click on the "edit(1)" button on my original question, I am shown an edit proposed by another user.   However, if I click reject, I cannot find a way to click one of the radio buttons indicating why I want to reject the edit. In the screenshot below, you can see the "Why are you rejecting this edit" window out of focus behind the proposed edit pane.   If I try clicking there, it cancels the original proposed edit pane and starts me back at square one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. Details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349770/105971) on MSO. Thanks!